# my standardscaler outputs ValueError: could not convert string to float

Tags: python, pandas, machine-learning, scikit-learn

I am doing a project as a python and machine learning beginner and came across Titanic dataset. After splitting my dataset into training and testing, I wanted to normalize the `x_train` using `StandardScaler`, but this keeps coming out:

> ValueError: could not convert string to float: 'PassengerId'

and this is my code

```
    feature =df[['PassengerId', 'PClass', 'Age', 'SibSp', 'Parch']].values
    target = df[['Survived']].values
    x_train, x_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(feature, target, test_size=0.2)
    from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler, OneHotEncoder
    scaler = StandardScaler().fit(x_train)
    x_train = scaler.transform(x_train)
    x_test = scaler.transform(x_test)
```

How can I solve this?

Answer (score 0):

```
# it's a good idea to exclude PassengerId, since it's probabaly not a predictive feature
# also convert all the values to float
feature =df[['PClass', 'Age', 'SibSp', 'Parch']].astype('float').values
target = df[['Survived']].values
    
x_train, x_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(feature, target, test_size=0.2)
from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler, OneHotEncoder
scaler = StandardScaler().fit(x_train)
x_train = scaler.transform(x_train)
x_test = scaler.transform(x_test)
```

Comment: now it is giving me ValueError: could not convert string to float: 'Pclass'